# git repository in repository scenario: how to ignore repository subfolders (i.e. subfolders having .git/)

Tags: git

Suppose I have my repository structure like this:

```
MyApp/
    .git/
    .gitignore
    File1
    dir1/
        File2
    src/
        File3
        File4
        module1/
            .git/
            .gitignore
            foo.cpp
        module2/
            .git/
            .gitignore
            bar.cpp
        ...
```

In other words, I have some deep sub-folders containing `.git/`, called repository sub-folders.

How can I write `.gitignore` in MyApp repository, or by other means, to ignore all those repository sub-folders in the view of MyApp?  They are obvious to be ignored, since they are already managed by other independent repositories.

--OR--

Any standard way to deal with this "Git: repository in repository" scenario, if the "ignoring" is not the way to go?

Comment: Someone who left a -1 score, could you please explain? So that I can improve the way I asked the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My intention is to automatically ignores folders containing `.git/`

Those folder contents are *already* ignored, as a main Git repo would only record them as [**gitlink**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) ([special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)).
Here it would only record `module1`, `module2` (not their content)

If you wanted to *not* record module1, you would still need a .gitignore (with simply a `src/module*`, no trailing slash as you do not ignore a folder, only a gitlink)
You cannot instruct git to automatically ignore a gitlink, you have to specify it in a .gitignore.

Comment: This seems not true.   At least in my cygwin git: Files like `1.c` and `2.c` inside a lower repository can be added into the upper git repository.

Comment: What git version are you using? No need for cygwin, git for Windows is enough.

Comment: You are right!  Git for Windows automatically skip sub-repositories!  It's just strange to me that the Git version on Cygwin is higher (2.8.3), than Git for windows (2.6.3).

Comment: @RobinHsu Git for Windows is at 2.11: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases

Comment: OK.  But I mean I am using previous Git for Windows version 2.6.3, and it can ignore sub-repositories.  However, my cygwin git @ v2.8.3 can not. That's strange.

Answer (score 0):

I'm understanding your question correctly, then although not "automatically ignoring via .git identification", an easy way to ignore the module1,2....n sub trees is to create a .gitignore file in myApp/src folder and insert the value:

```
module*/
```

Then save the file and you should achieve the desired result.

Comment: To match only directories, write `module*/`, i.e., have a trailing slash.

Comment: thanks @j6t! have tested and enhanced my answer accordingly